# How to use multiple cores in the JAVA Non Blocking I/O (NIO) API?

Tags: java, nio

JAVA NIO provides an API to write a TCP server using NIO architecture, as follows.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.*;

public class NIOServer implements Runnable{
    private InetAddress addr;
    private int port;
    private Selector selector;

    public NIOServer(InetAddress addr, int port) throws IOException {
        this.addr = addr;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            startServer();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void startServer() throws IOException {

        this.selector = Selector.open();
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = serverSocketChannel.open();
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        InetSocketAddress listenAddr = new InetSocketAddress(this.addr, this.port);
        serverChannel.socket().bind(listenAddr);
        serverChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);


        while (true) {

            this.selector.select();


            Iterator keys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keys.next();


                keys.remove();

                if (! key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    this.accept(key);
                }
                else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    this.read(key);
                }
                else if (key.isWritable()) {
                    this.write(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This uses a single thread that will process events such as read, write and accept.

Compared to Blocking thread per connection architecture this is much preferred because of its non-blocking nature that causes minimum cache misses, thread overheads, low cpu migrations.

However, this architecture uses only a single thread. In a multi-process environment (for example 4 core cpu), NIO architecture wastes other cores. Is there a design approach I can use to utilize all the cores with NIO architecture?

NIO2 (which is based on proactor pattern) is one such option. But the underlying architecture is very different to original NIO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the basic idea of this is to **split the task**:

```java
    ExecuterService workers = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);

    ....
    while (true) {

                this.selector.select();

                Iterator keys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) keys.next();

                    keys.remove();

                    if (! key.isValid()) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                        this.accept(key);
                    }
                    else if (key.isReadable()) {
                        workers.execute(new ReadTaskHandler(key));
                    }
                    else if (key.isWritable()) {
                        workers.execute(new WriteTaskHandler(key));
                    }
                }
            }
```

```
class ReadTaskHandler implements Runnable {
    SelectionKey key;

    public ReadTaskHandler(SelectionKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        int size = 0;
        try {
            while ((size = channel.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                System.out.println(new String(buffer.array()));
                buffer.flip();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, there are many models about NIO. For example, we can also use multiple threads to handle the accept task(also called **multiple reactors** model or **multiple eventloop** model).

BTW, Netty is a great event-driven network application framework packaged java NIO

Comment: According the NIO2 (which is based on proactor pattern) your mentioned, I'd like to share some discussions about NIO vs NIO2(AIO) :https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2515
There are no performance improvement by using NIO2 especially on LInux, because it was using the same OS facility - epoll.

Comment: I have used the above approach and it does not significantly improve the performance, specialy when the processing requirement of the request is low.  However, as you have mentioned,  multiple reactors model or multiple eventloop model seems more promising. Can you please explain this method?

Comment: @PasinduTennage Firstly, compared with BIO, NIO won't make huge improvement if there're not enough connections/requests (based on my experience maybe connections < 2000) . The advantage of NIO is that you can use a few threads to handle a lot of connections, imagining that 2000 connections will cost 2000 threads in BIO model. Thread is a kind of expensive resource. 
Actually, as for my approach vs. your version, it needs much more connections to show the performance difference(probably up to 10k ~ 50k connections/ per second).

Comment: @PasinduTennage Again, keep in mind that thread is expensive. The numbers of threads should be flexible according the real connections and the CPU cores, and  too many threads may make bad impacts in performance cause it's cost a lot time to switch  thread context.
and regarding the "multiple reactors" model, it is for more huge throughput. You can see my approach as 1 master/boss with many slaves/workers, so "multiple reactors"   
is 1~3 master/boss with many slaves/worker. "multiple reactors" can make improvement only when performance bottleneck is in accepting connections.

Comment: Illustration for mainReactors, subReactors with many workers: https://user-gold-cdn.xitu.io/2018/11/5/166e31ccfc6fd6b1?imageslim